# RegEx match for input name

Tags: regex, arrays

I'm trying to clone input fields with JS and increment their `id` and `name` so I can validate them. Here's an example:

```
<input type="text" id="work_company0" name="work[0][company]" />
<input type="text" id="work_company1" name="work[1][company]" />

<input type="text" id="work_title0" name="work[0][title]" />
<input type="text" id="work_title1" name="work[1][title]" />
```

So for the `id`, the regex would be:

```
/^(.*)(\d)+$/i
```

For `id="work_company1"`, the match results in `["work_company1", "work_company", "1"]` and I create the new ID by using `match[1] + newID` (work_company2).

What would be the regex for the `name` to get a similar match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
var s = 'work[1][title]';
var r = /\w+\[(\d+)\]\[(\w+)\]/;
var m = s.match(r);

// in m variable m[1] is id and m[2] is name
```

hope this makes sense.

Comment: The match for the ID resulted in ["work_title1", "work_title", "1"] and then I used m[1] + newID to get the new ID (work_title2).

This match results in ["work[1][title]", "1", "title"]. Is there a way to get ["work[1][title]", "work[", "][title]"] so I can insert the new ID in there?

Comment: Figured it out. It's /(\w+\[)(\d+)(\]\[\w+\])/ So for work[1][title], the match results in ["work[1][title]", "work[", "1", "][title]"] - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

*ID or NAME*

```
\b(?:id|name)="[^\"]+"
```

**validation[NAME]**

```
\b(?:name)="work\[\d+\]\[company\]"
```